# Summing up multiple columns values into one single column in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, summarizing

I have one table containing many columns. Using the Field Calculator, I want to create a new column containing (for each line) the sum of all columns values.

I cannot find the correct expression to do this sum.

Answer (score 7):

Using the Field calculator to:

- sum up columns without `NULL` values:

  ```
  "column1" + "column2" + "column3"
  ```
- sum up columns with `NULL` values:

  ```
  "column1" +  (CASE WHEN  "column2" IS NOT NULL THEN "column2" ELSE 0 END) + "column3"
  ```

Make sure the columns are integer or float values.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I've been trying but it doesn't work. I was wondering if it was me or some other sort of problem. Glad to know it's not me !

Comment: Can you please specify what do you mean by it doesn't work at all or it gives you incorrect results?

Comment: It doesn't work at all. I get only NULL values. It also desn't show any preview result in the field calculator.

Comment: @Legzav: Can you confirm that all the columns (input and output) are of Numeric Data type?

Comment: Yes, all columns are REAL, 20 length, 5 precision. Many fields have NULL value. Don't know if this can have an impact !? should I replace all NULL by 0 ?

Comment: Yes, I see, the sum does not work in case there are NULL values. I accordingly updated my answer. That seems to be a shortcoming in the field calculator.

Comment: Seems logic to me, NULL is not a value, therefore the calculator does not know what to do with it. You will have to choose what to do with it yourself. Instead of changing your data, you could try use conditionals (CASE WHEN) to convert your NULL fields to 0 (Or other value you need).

Comment: Hem one more question: I found how to change the NULL to 0 but I have many columns and don't whant to edit them. I've been using : case when "Field_Name" is NULL then '0' else "field_Name" end  Now could anyone tell me which syntax I should use to make my sum without first editing all these NULL ? I'm blocked here... or any website where I could learn the basics ?

Comment: Yes, you can use conditionals. See my updated answer.

Comment: How can we add two text or strings ? `Col1 + Col2 = Col1Col2`

Comment: Got it! I used `Concat()`