# Summing values from spatially joined table with QGIS Field Calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, spatial-join, expression, summarizing

Can the Field Calculator be used to sum values from a related table via a Spatial Join?

I have two vector polygon layers A and B, each with a numerical column VALUES.  I want to update `"VALUES"` in layer A with the sum of `"VALUES"` from layer B where geometry from B is contained within geometry A.

So far I have the expression:

```
geomcontains('Layer B', 'VALUES')
```

and what I want is, to sum up, this.

I have seen other ways to do this via plugins like SpatialJoin etc, but they all involve modifying either saving new layers or modifying the structure of Layer A, which I think is fairly cumbersome - is there a simple solution? (In MapInfo this is extremely simple, using Update Column)

Comment: (I have the refFunctions plugin installed, which includes the function 'geomcontains')

Comment: While there are ways to make them do so, Field Calculators typically don't work with multiple rows/records in a calculation - they're designed to operate on multiple fields within a single row. You're looking for basically a Summary Statistics tool as it's known in ArcGIS. The GroupStats plugin might meet your needs for QGIS. But you will have to generate a summary table and then join that back to A to update the fields. This question might also help: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73681/

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's taken me nearly 8 years but I finally found the answer!

Open Field Calculator to update field `"VALUE_A"` in Layer A, and use the following expression:

```
aggregate('Layer B', 'sum', "VALUE_B", within(centroid($geometry), geometry(@parent)))
```

Use Show Help to learn other functions you can use in each of the arguments:

```
aggregate(layer,aggregate,expression[,filter][,concatenator=''][,order_by])
```

I have found this does time out for larger datasets, if this is an issue then you can select a subset of overlapping polygons in both Layer A and Layer B, check 'Only update selected features' (in Layer A), and use the following modified expression:

```
aggregate('Layer B', 'sum', "VALUE_B", is_selected('Layer B', @feature) AND within(centroid($geometry), geometry(@parent)))
```

Finally, if you wanted to update with a text value from the containing polygon you can use `'min'` as the aggregate instead of `'sum'`.

Comment: I should say, thanks to @Zoltan who suggested to use the 'aggregate' function for a similar question:
[link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/383202/updating-attributes-between-layers-with-a-spatial-join) https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/383202/updating-attributes-between-layers-with-a-spatial-join

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Toolbox for the spatial join (Processing Toolbox > search: [Join by Location](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_general_tools/joinatributesbylocation.html)) and save the result to a temporary layer. The temporary layer is only saved in your QGIS project. Then you can join the temporary layer to *'layer A'*.

[image]

You can find the processing toolbox in `View > Panels > Toolbox` or right-click over the toolbars.

Comment: In QGIS 3 this appears to be renamed "Join attributes by location (summary)"

Answer (score 1):

As it says on the ["refFunctions"](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/refFunctions/) plugin's page:

> This plugin is deprecated!
>
> The plugin is outdated as of QGIS 3.14 due to the introduction of the
> new functions for geometry overlay expressions

[Since QGIS 3.16](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog316/index.html#port-reffunctions-to-core) the functionality of the "refFunctions" plugin was conveyed to the QGIS core.

---

The ["refFunctions"](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/refFunctions/) plugin offers `intersecting_geom_sum()` function to do that task.

Activate the Field Calculator on your `Layer A` and try,

```
intersecting_geom_sum('Layer B', 'VALUES')
```

This function sums the geometries' attributes (`Values` in your case) of the target layer (your `Layer B`).